# Combine other columns as JSON without aggregating

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a query with a number of columns in Postgres. All of the columns except for the other two are to be combined as a JSON in single result. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT  date_time, id, 
        json_build_object(
            'col1', json_agg(col1),
            'col2', json_agg(col2),
            ...
            'coln', json_agg(coln)
        ) AS attributes
FROM mytable;
```

The problem is that the query complains that it requires aggregation on the other two columns not belonging to JSON. I don't want to aggregate, I simply want to JSONize the other columns per row.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT  date_time, id, 
        to_json(col1, col2, ..., coln)
FROM mytable;
```

but didn't work. How should I structure my query and/or what Postgres JSON function should I use?

I am using Postgres v9.6.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to aggregate, then don't aggregate:

```
SELECT  date_time, id, 
        json_build_object(
            'col1', col1,
            'col2', col2,
            'coln', coln
        ) AS attributes FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution (at least for some cases):

```
SELECT date_time, id, 
       row_to_json(m.*)::jsonb #- '{date_time}' #- '{id}' AS attributes
  FROM mytable;
```